# IAR Embedded Workbench: Illegal Opcode Found on Adress 0x0

Tags: assembly, msp430

There are similar questions to this one, but I could not solve my problem after looking others. I am trying to simulate interrupt, but when it comes to activating the interrupt, this error is happening. Here is my code;

```
#include "msp430.h"                     ; #define controlled include file

        NAME    main                    ; module name

        PUBLIC  main                    ; make the main label vissible
                                        ; outside this module
        ORG     0FFFEh
        DC16    init                    ; set reset vector to 'init' label

        org     0ffe4h
        dc16    int


        RSEG    CSTACK                  ; pre-declaration of segment
        RSEG    CODE                    ; place program in 'CODE' segment

init:   MOV     #SFE(CSTACK), SP        ; set up stack

main:   NOP                             ; main program
        MOV.W   #WDTPW+WDTHOLD,&WDTCTL  ; Stop watchdog timer
         bis.b #041h,P1DIR  
         bis.b #0Eh,&P1IE 
         bis.b #0Eh,&P1IES 
         bis.b #0Eh,&P1OUT 
         bic.b #0Eh,&P1IFG 
         eint 
         mov #07fffh,r7 
mainloop xor.b #01h,&P1OUT
         call #delay
         jmp mainloop

int      bit.b #08h,&P1IFG 
         jz no1 
         sub #07000,r7 
         jmp exit

no1 bit.b #04h,&P1IFG 
       jz no2 
       add #07000,r7 
       jmp exit
no2    nop 
       nop 
       xor.b #040h,&P1OUT 
       nop 
exit call #delay2 
      bic.b #0Eh,&P1IFG 
      reti
delay mov r7,r8 
loop   dec r8
      jnz loop
      ret
delay2 mov #020000,r5  
loop2 dec R5 
       jnz loop2 
       ret


       JMP $                           ; jump to current location '$'
                                        ; (endless loop)
        END
```

I hope you can help me solve this problem. Have a nice day!

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to rewrite all your comments and label names in english when posting the code here.

Comment: I have edited the post. I have removed unnecessary comments and have translated label names into English.

Comment: What is the address of the code segment?